# Massively struggling with laying out DirectX and windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx

I have managed to get this example to work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370994(v=vs.85).aspx

My problem is that I am trying to structure the code there into something more understandable...

My first step is to remove all the stuff that's not absolutely necessary to lanching a window with a direct x surface... but as soon as I start messing with the code, I get massively confused at which components are core, and which are not...

Do you know of a kind of boilerplate project with literally the utmost basics in it for a directx surface in a window.

D2D is fine unless you suggest I just code straight in D3D... even though i'm only going to be drawing 2d stuff.

I've read so many resources and tutorials for directX but every blooming one has different bits and bobs placed in and it's so difficult to just learn what the "must" bits are!...

Just to help you with the question.

I have started by trying to create a Gfx object that will start and create surfaces and resources for direct X, I also tried to separate my windows code but ofcourse got a bit lost there too... Finally I wrapped up my Game class so that the windows loop just ran begin draw, render and end draw. in the tutorial above you have 2 brushes which as i'm not familiar with directX, I'm unsure if I can just whip them out completely or what?

I guess a step in the right direction is really what i'm looking for.

Comment: Old dx9 sdk (from 2008/9) used to come with samples, one of which was a very minimalistic project. Not sure what new ones are like, but if they don't have anything similar you could just comment out bits until what you have stops working :P

Comment: Mike, do you know lots about DirectX... I'll give you some money if you can help me out here... I'm so desperate to get this working

Comment: I'm sorry I already have a job, and I haven't worked with DX for years anyway.

Comment: Aww, this isn't for a job.. this is for me being able to make a game for fun :( Okay no problems, perhaps someone has some resource somewhere which may be a little more helpful. Thanks for your time!.. Perhaps I should have mentioned "I'd buy you a beer" rather than i'd give you some money hah. I'm so bummed out. I've spent 150 hours+ learning c++ and now am completely stuck on DX lol

Comment: I voted to close this question (really, this is not a concrete question that someone can answer here... the closest thing would be a tutorial, but you already got stuck on those), but know that I *do sympathise*. This stuff can be a beast getting into! The best advice would be to get a good book as it puts things into the correct context... or even better, find someone in real life who knows about this stuff, so can have a short and effective feedback cycle going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very strongly suggest that you get hold of a decent book that can guide you through the steps:

For example - [try to get a copy of this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936420228)

Comment: Does this book give any insight into windows 8 store apps too? Not that i'm too fussed. Just would be nice

Comment: No - that's totally different, but there is a free ebook on Microsoft's web site that does exactly that.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/10/29/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that. I have purchased the book any way, mainly for a reference and I'm hoping it will give me a nice example of someone elses layout... I have watched all the tutorials supplied by PLANET CHILI DIRECTX and it may be best to just find out how others lay their initial build out.

Comment: By the way, having a look at your link... Windows 8 store apps can be created using Direct X 11.1 and C++. it has 4 choices, XAMLL (some C# XML format styling), c++ D3D and c++ D2D and finally html 5 with javascript. The latter is not really valid for making fast games. If you create a fresh Windows 8 store app project using D3D c++, it seems to have a few more bits and bobs for touch import and screen rotation etc.... that's all. Thanks for your help though!